# Jquery Plugin - Type in text field with box for field hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

This is hard to explain. I had seen a plugin that allowed the user to type into a text field that was hidden. All you noticed was a cursor and the text being typed. If you've seen the new MySpace video. You can see what I'm talking about in there. Sorry this wasn't better explained.

Comment: Please post up the code you have tried. You should be able to do this in CSS by changing the opacity of the text box.

Comment: @joshuahornby10 - Here is what I was looking for. In the screen shot that shows "childish..." Above that is also a description of the functionality. You can see how large the font is with no visible field the text is being entered into.  [link](http://www.webpronews.com/new-myspace-a-first-look-at-the-huge-redesign-2012-12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this and it wasn't by using a Jquery plugin, something I thought would have been created.

Setting background to transparent is what did the trick. I also needed the user to be able to type anywhere on the screen and the text show up in the text area. This was accomplished with the JS below.

```
$( document ).on( 'keydown', function( ev ) {
var nodeName = ev.target.nodeName;
if ( 'INPUT' == nodeName || 'TEXTAREA' == nodeName ) {
    return;
}
$( '#text' ).val( '' ).trigger( 'focus' );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from disabling CSS from your browser, you cannot type into a textbox which is hidden.

However, you can make the textbox *appear* to be hidden by using blank styles:

```
input.hidden { 
   border:0;
   outline: none;
}
```

In the following demo, click just to the right of the first textbox, and you will be able to start typing (although the textbox appears hidden):

[**-- See Demo --**](http://jsfiddle.net/hy34Y/1/)